# Kotlin BottomNavigationView.selectedItemId trigger OnBackStackChangedListener

Tags: android, kotlin

I have multiple fragment, one bottom navigation view on bottom of Main Activity. The problem appears when I want to set selected item on Bottom Navigation View when fragment pop back from stack, `setSelectedItemId always trigger OnBackStackChangedListener`, thus make loop event. Here are the code

```
fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener {
    var f : Fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frame)

    if(f is HomeFragment){ 
        bottomNavigation.selectedItemID = R.id.navigation_home
    }
}
```

I've check from the documentation at developer.android.com and various post on StackOverflow or even forum and I don't find any proper solution for my case.

Any solution? thanks

Comment: could you please post the part of code related to ,  BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, and BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener. i think that bottomNavigation.selectedItemId will notify the listener. so you are adding a new HomeFragment infinitly.